# How to inject SchedulerFactoryBean after Spring 4.3.15 update

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am getting the following error after upgrading from Spring 4.3.2 to Spring 4.3.16:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
```

I am injecting a Quartz Scheduler into one of my beans as follows:

// XML Config

```
<bean id="schedulerFactory" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" autowire="byName">
    <property name="jobFactory">
        <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory"/>
    </property>
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDS" />
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="updateTrigger"/>
            <ref bean="queueUpdateTrigger"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">MyQuartzScheduler</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">60000</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">QRTZ_</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">2</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">5</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="UpdateJobUtils" class="app.job.UpdateJobUtils" autowire="byType">
    <property name="schedulerFactory" ref="schedulerFactory" />
</bean>
```

//Bean

```
public class UpdateJobUtils {
    private StdScheduler schedulerFactory;

    public void setSchedulerFactory(StdScheduler schedulerFactory) {
        this.schedulerFactory = schedulerFactory;
    }

    ...
}
```

This worked in Spring 4.3.2 up until 4.3.14. I see https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16439 was backported to 4.3.15 so I am wondering if it changes the way I am supposed to use this class?

Answer (score 0):

schedulerFactory had autowire="byName" on its configuration.

I am not sure why that was on there, but removing it seems to have fixed the exception.